# Add View port height to Javascript plugin

Tags: jquery, height, viewport

I have a javascript banner that has a default width and height, I would like to add the view port height to that. (I cant put 100% or auto, since the plugin doesnt work with that. I should add values like 100px etc). Below the is javascript

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   var h=$(window).height();
  $('#slideshow').fadeSlideShow({
        PlayPauseElement: false,
        NextElement: false,
        PrevElement: false,
        ListElement: false,
        width: '100%',
        height: h+'px'
    });

    });
</script>
```

Please advice me..

Many thanks

Comment: next time please don't modify your question as per the answer given (if there is not a typo in the question or mistake done by you at the time of posting) because this will confuse others referring to the question and they can interpret that the answering person is re-posting the question-code in the answer which will result in down-voting of the answer.

Comment: @UDB Pardon me for the mistake..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's

```
var h=$(window).height()
```

and in css (settings being passed to the plugin object) you have to write

```
$('#slideshow').fadeSlideShow({
    PlayPauseElement: false,
    NextElement: false,
    PrevElement: false,
    ListElement: false,
    width: '100%',
    height: h+'px';
});
```

**EDIT**  below is the example code for full screen slideshow using SimpleFadeSlideShow plugin. But I will still recommend to use images large enough according to the desired slide show size to prevent pixelation of images.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jq.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="slideshow/fadeslideshow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="slideshow/demostylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

var h=$(window).height();
var w=$(window).width();


$('#slideshow').css({
margin: '0px',
padding: '0px'
})

$('body').css('overflow','hidden')

$.when($('#slideshow').find('img').css
({
width: w+'px',
height: h+'px'
})

).then($('#slideshow').fadeSlideShow({
    PlayPauseElement: false,
    NextElement: false,
    PrevElement: false,
    ListElement: false,
    width: w+'px',
    height: h+'px'
})
)



$(window).on('resize',function(){

$(document).ready(function(){

$('body').css('overflow','visible')

$(window).scrollTop($(window).height())

$('#slideshow').find('*').css({

 width: $(window).width()+'px',
 height: $(window).height()+'px'
})

$('#slideshow').find('*').css({
   width: $(window).width()+20+'px',
   height: $(window).height()-$(window).scrollTop()+17+'px'
})

$(window).scrollTop(0);

$('body').css('overflow','hidden')

$('#slideshow').css({height : $(window).height()+'px', width: $(window).width()+'px'})


})
});
 });

</script>

</head>
<body>
<ul id="slideshow" style="width: 640px; height: 480px; position: relative; overflow: hidden;">

<!-- This is the last image in the slideshow--> 
<li style="position: absolute; width: 640px; height: 480px; display: list-item;">
    <img src="http://www.simplefadeslideshow.com/wp-content/themes/simplefadeslideshow_com/images/3.jpg" width="640" height="480" border="0" alt="">
</li>
<li style="position: absolute; width: 640px; height: 480px; display: list-item;">
    <img src="http://www.simplefadeslideshow.com/wp-content/themes/simplefadeslideshow_com/images/2.jpg" width="640" height="480" border="0" alt="">
</li>
<li style="position: absolute; width: 640px; height: 480px; display: list-item; opacity: 0.7128896457825363;">
    <img src="http://www.simplefadeslideshow.com/wp-content/themes/simplefadeslideshow_com/images/1.jpg" width="640" height="480" border="0" alt="">
</li>
<!-- This is the first image in the slideshow -->
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried to add the values to the css, but its only taking the height from the javascript
 $('#slideshow').fadeSlideShow({
  PlayPauseElement: false,
  NextElement: false,
  PrevElement: false,
  ListElement: false,
  width: '100%',
  height: h,// here i need to add
 });

Comment: @Gops i am not getting you what do you mean by `taking height from javascript`?

Comment: I tried to add a style sheet like #slideshow li img {height:900 px; width:100%} but when the script renders it only gives the height that is given in the javascript..

Comment: I have updated my script with what you have given.. Still its not taking the height.. Pls review the script

Comment: @Gops i have tested the plugin by creating a web page.Giving viewport height or width to the plugin will only change the dimensions of slideshow box not the images, so if images are small it doesn't matter how much the width or height you supply you will not get the fullscreen slideshow. So you can use images that are large according to your requirement or just wait for some time i will see if i can do something

Comment: @Gops i have edited the answer, you can copy the code and use it in your browser to see the result but do not forget to change the script and css path in the `head`

Comment: Thanks a ton.. it's working now.. One clarification though, what if someone re-size the page. How to capture the resized width and height. Any ways thanks for your valuable time and expertise.. :)

Comment: @Gops you acn use `$(window).resize()` or `$(window).on('resize')`. But the resize part was tricky so i have re-edited the answer to include the window resize code.